# magento transactional emails CC

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, magento

is it possible to addcc on a magento transactional email?

I know I can getMail() to return a Zend_Mail object which I can then addCC()....But that doesn't appear to actually attach my extra email address.

Comment: <sigh>  fixed it...guess it helps if you try to add the CC before you actually send the email out!

Comment: Is it possible to add a CC filed on the backend order entry form? This would be useful (for example) a wholesale order where the sales rep,

Answer (score 0):

single email or array email is acceptable, check this out:

> app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template

public function addBcc($bcc)
{
    if (is_array($bcc)) {
        foreach ($bcc as $email) {
            $this->getMail()->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    elseif ($bcc) {
        $this->getMail()->addBcc($bcc);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,no need to overwrite the core modules

```
 try{
      $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
      $mail->getMail()->addCc('abc@gmail.com');  

      $mail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
```